# BibTeX warning that optional fields are empty

Tags: bibtex, warnings

I've got the following .bib file (Material.bib):

```
@manual{GHCUserGuide,
  author = {The GHC Team},
  title = {The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System User's Guide},
  number = {7.6.3},
  institution={University Court of the University of Glasgow},
  year = {2013},
  month = {April}
}

@techreport{Haskell_1_3,
  author = {John Peterson and others},
  title = {Report on the Programming Language Haskell},
  institution = {Various institutions},
  year = {1996},
  month = {May}
}
```

and the following tex file:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\nocite{Haskell_1_3}
\nocite{GHCUserGuide}

\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
\bibliography{Material}


\end{document}
```

When running BibTeX, I get the following warnings:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
The top-level auxiliary file: BibTeX.aux
The style file: alphadin.bst
Database file #1: Material.bib
Warning--empty number in Haskell_1_3
Warning--empty note in Haskell_1_3
Warning--empty edition in GHCUserGuide
Warning--empty address in GHCUserGuide
(There were 4 warnings)
```

That's strange because all the mentioned fields in the output are *optional* and not *required* for the given entry types. What's the reason for this behaviour and is there any way to get rid of the warning messages without having to add the fields to the .bib-file?

Comment: My test turns out correct. No warnings. My system is Vista, MiKTeX2.9 and TeXworks editor.

Comment: That's _really_ strange. I've also got MiKTeX2.9, but Windows 8. I'm using the editor WinEdt 7.1, but that shouldn't matter. Do you invoke BibTeX from the command line or from the editor? I invoke BibTeX on the command line without extra parameters.

Comment: I just used WinEdt 5 to run your case again. Same result as the first result I reported. I simply click the pdflatex . Note: You could install MiKTeX-portable from the website in a usb. Such approach is useful in such case for different platform to check what went wrong.

Comment: @Jesse, the error report is from bibtex, not pdflatex...

Comment: @M.B. the fields you've mentioned are _optional_ for standard `alpha` style, but probably they are _required_ for `alphadin`

Comment: @karlkoeller -- Both styles pass my compilations.

Comment: @Jesse -- 'pass' is misleading: a 'warning' is a warning, not an error, so the file will be created.  @M.B. should read the comments in `alphadin.bst` and confirm that he is constructing entries correctly.  On a Unix-ish system, you can do this (e.g.) by typing `less $(kpsewhich alphadin.bst)` (or substitute for your favourite editor).

Comment: @jon -- thanks for the comment. Indeed, I should have noticed key points.

Comment: How do you know they are not required? It is the given `.bst` that defines what is required. An option may be truely options in one style, but required in another. Though, I've never seen a reuired `note` before.

Comment: I just looked into the bibtex/bst directory of my MiKTeX distribution and found out that there is no bst file named "alphadin.bst" at all! So I changed the bibliography style to "alpha" and the warnings disappeared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `alphadin.bst` file is present in TeX Live

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/din1505/alphadin.bst
```

and it uses slightly different rules for the fields. The classification of fields into mandatory and optional for a particular entry type depends on the bibliography style. It happens that `alphadin.bst` requires those fields for those entry types, so BibTeX warns when it doesn't find them.

The documentation about the `din1505` styles can be found at

http://mirror.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/german/din1505/normpatsoft.pdf

and its title is

> Bibtex–Beispiele für Normen, Patente und Software nach Abschnitt 6.4, 6.5 und 6.8 der Norm DIN 1505 Teil 2

so they seem very specialized bibliography styles, for which it's clear that particular rules are applied.